# How to find who is setting an interface?

Tags: networking, systemd, udev

I have a computer with ubuntu 20.04 and two LAN ports. I want the left one to be eth0 and the other eth1.
I therefore wrote a udev rule

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add",  ATTR{address}=="<mac left>", NAME:="eth0"
```

and placed it under */etc/udev/rules.d/10-eth0.rules*. I then expected the renaming to happen when I reboot...
But after reboot eth0 and eth1 are still swapped and journalctl tells me:

```
eth1: Failed to rename network interface 3 from 'eth1' to 'eth0': File exists
eth1: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
```

So it seems something is setting the interface names even before udev runs? I have been googling for the last few days to find the cause of it and can't find anything applicable.
Suggestions are to check "sysconfig", which of course does not exist in ubuntu, or NetworkManager, which I don't have installed. I also don't have netplan installed, but I do have ifupdown. Ifupdown should use the */etc/network/interfaces* file for configuration but there is only the rule for the *lo* interface.

Is there a way to check who is setting the interface and why is this happening before udev kicks in?

Comment: What does: `sudo dmesg | grep eth` tell us?

Comment: igb 0000:02:00.0: added PHC on eth0

igb 0000:02:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:02

igb 0000:02:00.0: eth0: PBA No: 200500-000

e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:01

e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection

e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth1: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF